# Hadoop ecosystem web dashboard

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to find a tool, which would show me an overview of my Hadoop ecosystem - state, health, running tasks, etc. I tried to Google, but did not find any. Is there some nice useful tool?

Answer (score 1):

Running tasks, mapred node state/health:

http://example.com:50030/jobtracker.jsp

HDFS health and node state:

http://example.com:50070/dfshealth.jsp

Replace example.com with the IP or hostname of your job tracker / name node.

If those ports aren't correct check your mapred-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml for the defined port.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudera offers a proprietary tool which does what you describe and more called [Cloudera Manager](http://www.cloudera.com/products-services/tools/).  It isn't F/OSS, but they do have a free edition that lets you run on some limited number of nodes.  It's meant as a full lifecycle product, so it might be a bit overkill for what you need.

Full disclosure: I've never used it myself.  We considered it at my company, but ended up not using it.

Comment: The limitation was lifted with the release of Cloudera Manager 4.5.  Previously it was 50 nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is the [Ambari](http://incubator.apache.org/ambari/) project.  It's currently in incubation status at Apache, but I believe [Hortonworks](http://www.hortonworks.com/) is one of the major drivers for it.  It's primarily a provisioning and monitoring framework.  You can see [examples](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop/ambari/) at Hortonworks' website.  They did a blog post describing [how to set it up](http://hortonworks.com/kb/get-started-setting-up-ambari/).

If you're looking for a "prettier" interface to the jobtracker or namenode, [Cloudera](http://www.cloudera.com/) has the [Hadoop User Environment (HUE)](http://cloudera.github.io/hue/#home), which provides some of the functionality you're looking for.  It's geared towards non-administrators for the most part, though.